# How to convert "\/Date(1262300400000+0100)\/" to Java Date instance and vice versa?

Tags: java, android

I am getting on android client from C# server Date like string with format `"\/Date(1262300400000+0100)\/"`.  (part of json object)
How to convert this to Java Date instance and vice versa ?
I need to show this in readable format.

Comment: Dude you found any solution or format for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the numbers:

```
String numbers = str.replaceAll("\\\\/Date\\((\\d+\\+\\d+)\\)\\\\/", "$1+$2");
```

Split on the plus (+) sign.

```
String parts = numbers.split("\\+");
```

Convert to Date:

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(parts[0]));
```

However, I'm not sure on what to do with the TimeZone.